# what is the opposite of the stretch?

Tags: adjectives, antonyms

As I have checked some online dictionaries, I have found 'shorten' and 'shrink' as opposites of the 'stretch' word. But, I am not sure, yet.

As an example, suppose that shrink is the correct word, then I say in this figure[image]

I am shrinking the plot from top to bottom or stretching vice-versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shrink can work. I would also consider "compress" as a good option. "Reduce" can also work

> I reduced the plot vertically

You could ask this on English Language and Usage to get additional ideas.

Answer (score 2):

When I think of the opposite of *stretch*, I think *squeeze*.